# Converting QBasic CHR$(13)+CHR$(10) to C#

Tags: c#, string, serial-port, ascii, qbasic

I'm trying to pass a straight ASCII text command through my serial port, something like this:

```
string cmd = "<ID00><PA>Hello World. ";
template.Serial.WriteLine(cmd);
```

Serial being a SerialPort property reference.  I've also tried 'Write(cmd)' but even though the serial port is open the command never seems to go through. I've found that I'm supposed to add a Carriage return (cr) and a Line Feed (lf) to the end of the message, but I don't know how to do this in C# short of converting everything to bytes but It needs to be passed as ASCII Text from my understanding of the protocol.

I found someone's QBasic source that looks like this:

```
100 OPEN "COM1:9600,N,8,1,CS,DS,CD" AS 1
200 PRINT #1,"<ID00>";:REM SIGN ADDRESS, 00 FOR ALL
210 PRINT #1,"<PA>";:REM PAGE "A" (MESSAGE NUMBER, A-Z)
220 PRINT #1,"<FQ>";:REM OPTIONAL DISPLAY MODE, (FA-FZ), "APPEAR"
230 PRINT #1,"<CB>";:REM OPTIONAL COLOR CHANGE, (CA-CZ), "RED"
240 PRINT #1,"Hello World";:REM TEXT
250 PRINT #1, CHR$(13)+CHR$(10);:REM MUST END IN CARRIAGE RETURN/LINE FEED
```

So how would you convert CHR$(13)+CHR$(10) to characters that you append to the end of a string line in c# code to be sent through a serial port?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976240/c-sharp-char-from-int-used-as-string-the-real-equivalent-of-vb-chr

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In literal terms, `CHR$(13)+CHR$(10)` is `((char)13) + ((char)10)`, although for legibility, it would be better to use the string `"\r\n"`

Comment: "\r\n" worked like a charm, I've been working on this for almost a week now, thanks for the help... :)

Answer (score 0):

Append `System.Environment.NewLine` to your string. This is the equivalent of "\r\n" on Windows systems (but it will not work on Unix systems).

Comment: Not actually a good idea, he needs \r\n, not the system's default.

Comment: That's true but in most cases this will be equivalent to the old vbCrLf.