# C# Char from Int used as String - the real equivalent of VB Chr()

Tags: c#, string, vba, casting, char

I am trying to find a clear answer to my question and it is **not** a duplicate of any other questions on the site. I have read many posts and related questions on this on SO and several other sites. For example this one which is the key answer (many others are marked off as dulpicates and redirect to this one): [What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721201/whats-the-equivalent-of-vbs-asc-and-chr-functions-in-c)

I was converting a VBA macro to C#. And in VBA `chr(7)` can simply be concatenated to a `string` as if `chr()` would yield a `string`. Why can't this be done in C#?

And unfortunately the answer is not clear and many times they state that this is a correct use:

```
string mystring=(char)7;
```

Yet it gives me a compiler error as it does not evaluate as a string.

I had to use this to make it work:

```
string mystring=((char)7).ToString();
```

This would be the equivalent of the VB Chr() function, really as Chr() in VB evaluates as a string.

My question is this: do I always need to cast the `char` over to `string` explicitly or there are some cases where it converts over implicitly?

**UPDATE:**

Per @Dirk's answer, this also works:

```
string mystring = "" + (char)7;
```

This does not lessen my mystery. If concatenation works why there is no implicit cast??

I would like to get a full explanation on the difference between the VB Chr() and its equivalents in C#. I would appreciate any reference where I can read up on, or even examples would do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There is no implicit cast unless you implement that cast yourself.

Comment: A line of code did not give a compiler error, only at build time, which made me to start looking for the answer. The line of code was: `if (oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.EndsWith((char)7)` And when I looked many posts stated what I have in my OP. This is what I want to clarify and make sure I have it right: that one always have to cast to `string` if he wants to use it as `string`.

Comment: [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx), `Chr` returns a `Char`. Is it possible that VB just has an implicit cast from `Char` to `String`?

Comment: "did not give a compiler error, only at build time" What's the difference between the compiler and build time?

Comment: The difference is the real time compiling errors VS 2013 gives. It only reports the error when I build.

Comment: Why do you mention `Chr()` at all? Are you translating code from VB6 or something? `(char)7` means, exactly: convert an integer value, modulo 65536, as a UTF-16 code unit to the natural data type used for UTF-16 code units (`char`). (A `string` is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units.)

Comment: @TomBlodget -- Thanks. I updated the question. I offered the bounty to have this question fully explained so anybody, any noob can understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/721201/608639)

Comment: @jww Definitely not a duplicate. Please read the post and the accepted answer with bounty. This question and its answer does not locatable elsewhere on SO. If you read my post, I have linked this very question in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are opening Pandora's box with this question.  Chr() is a legacy function in VB.NET, any modern code should be using ChrW() instead.  The difference is the way the character value should be interpreted, ChrW() assumes the character code is Unicode (W = wide).  Chr() rolls back the clock to the previous century, a stone age without Unicode where characters were either in the ASCII character set (0..127) or an "extended" character (128..255).  Where the extended characters belong to a *code page*.  Many, many different code pages were in common use.  A very significant disaster, programs could not properly interpret text that was generated by another machine located in a different country.  Or even in the same country, Japan had multiple code pages in common use with none of them dominant.  Producing [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

I'll assume you mean ChrW(), nobody likes mojibake.  Not C# either.  Using Char.ToString() is fine, the alternative is to use the [string constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a `char`:

```
  string mystring = new string((char)7, 1);
```

Or the more general form you might prefer:

```
  public static string ChrW(int code) {
      return new string((char)code, 1);
  }
```

Not the only way to do it, using literals is possible as well and likely to be what you prefer over a helper method.  And the basic reason that C# does not need a helper function like Chr().  ASCII control code 7 is the bell character, it BEEPs you when you write it to the console, you can use an escape for that:

```
  string mystring = "\a";
```

Not exactly memorable, this comes from Unix.  Other ones are "\b" for backspace, "\t" for a tab, "\r" for a carriage return and "\n" for a line feed.  A classic trick to erase the last typed character in a console window is `Console.Write("\b \b");`.  The `Environment.NewLine` property should be noted.  Which is about as far as you should push it with control characters.

And last but not least the \U and \u specifier that lets you encode any character:

```
  string mystring = "\u0007";
```

Not obvious from the example but the \u value needs to be hexadecimal.  \U is needed when you use codepoints from the upper Unicode bit planes.

Comment: I like your simple approach of the explanation. I am rather new to C# and it was hard to switch gears on this one, so I am trying to make a full grip on this and I want it simple enough so that others like me won't have to search for as long as I had to.

Comment: Thanks.  Pandora's box has rarely simple content.

Comment: You know I am still wondering though, why it does not allow the simply cast to string like VB.NET? Meaning why is it better to just disallow it?

Comment: Automatic string conversions are dangerous, they get many vb.net programmers in trouble.  It is convenient but the C# designers decided that the danger outweighed the convenience.  C# is in general very strict, VB.NET is in general very convenient.  Basic reason why Microsoft provides two languages.

Comment: Nah, "not C# either" is as far as I want to take that.  SO users are passionate about their preferred language, as well they should be, they strongly dislike anything that resembles "you can't do that" or "it is harder".  They are both fine languages, just different.

Comment: Hey, a question: why is that so many upvoters on the answer (which really deserves it, don't get me wrong) but zero upvote on the question? I always upvote a good question that prompts a good answer. Any idea?

Comment: I see 2 votes on the question, that glass is infinitely more than empty.

Comment: Well maestro, thank you! I can't decide on the accept though, several of your guys' answer were just awesome...

Answer (score 6):

If you absolutely have to use the Chr method for legacy reasons of whatever, the best thing is to use it as a [normal method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr.aspx).

If you don't want to import VisualBasic, or want to see how it works, Reflector gives a nice piece of code:

```
public static char Chr(int CharCode)
{
    char ch;
    if ((CharCode < -32768) || (CharCode > 0xffff))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Argument_RangeTwoBytes1", new string[] { "CharCode" }));
    }
    if ((CharCode >= 0) && (CharCode <= 0x7f))
    {
        return Convert.ToChar(CharCode);
    }
    try
    {
        int num;
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Utils.GetLocaleCodePage());
        if (encoding.IsSingleByte && ((CharCode < 0) || (CharCode > 0xff)))
        {
            throw ExceptionUtils.VbMakeException(5);
        }
        char[] chars = new char[2];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
        Decoder decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
        if ((CharCode >= 0) && (CharCode <= 0xff))
        {
            bytes[0] = (byte) (CharCode & 0xff);
            num = decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, 1, chars, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            bytes[0] = (byte) ((CharCode & 0xff00) >> 8);
            bytes[1] = (byte) (CharCode & 0xff);
            num = decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, 2, chars, 0);
        }
        ch = chars[0];
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    return ch;
}
```

For an ASCII character, it just calls `Convert.ToChar`, which is equivalent to `(char)CharCode`. The first interesting thing is the call to `Utils.GetLocaleCodePage`:

```
internal static int GetLocaleCodePage()
{
    return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage;
}
```

Though one might expect it the same as `Encoding.Default`, it creates an encoding associated with the culture of the current thread, not the system. The rest is just stuffing the code into an array and using the encoding to decode it.

This method has one major caveat, as usual when dealing with encoding - it heavily depends on the current locale, and changing the culture of the current thread breaks all conversions for codes outside ASCII. But still, if *that's* what you want to do, here's a rough and short equivalent:

```
public static char Chr(int code)
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);
    return encoding.GetChars(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)code))[0];
}
```

This lacks some checks of the original method, especially the single-byte and range check.

Then there's a much simpler and much better method in VB.NET - [ChrW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Unicode:

```
public static char ChrW(int CharCode)
{
    if ((CharCode < -32768) || (CharCode > 0xffff))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Argument_RangeTwoBytes1", new string[] { "CharCode" }));
    }
    return Convert.ToChar((int) (CharCode & 0xffff));
}
```

This again falls back to [ToChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static char ToChar(int value)
{
    if ((value < 0) || (value > 0xffff))
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Char"));
    }
    return (char) value;
}
```

As you can see, ChrW is just the same as plain old `char` conversion... **except** for negative values! You know, although the character code has to fit into two bytes, it may have come from both signed or unsigned short, so the method makes sure it is the right number for both types of origin. If you want to take that into account, just do `CharCode & 0xffff`.

So as you can see, `Chr` is just `Encoding.GetChars` where the encoding is the current thread's one, and `ChrW` is just `(char)CharCode`, except that both functions also handle negative values. There is no other difference.

---

As for the original part of your question, you can't convert from `char` to `string` because... there is no possible conversion. They don't inherit each other, so you can't cast them, neither do they have any user-defined conversion operators, and `string` is not a primitive value type, so no built-in conversion either. VB.NET might allow you to do this, but all in all, it allows many worse things thanks to its ancient versions.

TL;DR Is `(char)` equivalent to `Chr`? Only for ASCII character code (0 to 127), otherwise **no**. And `Chr` stops working if the current encoding and the code encoding differ, which matter if you use non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 4):

Just to simplify the syntax. The following `AChar` class handles the conversions.

```
string A = (AChar)65;
Console.WriteLine(A); // output is "A"
```

The following class represents a character and defines conversions from ASCII code page:

```
struct AChar
{
    public static implicit operator AChar(char value) => new AChar { Value = value };

    public static explicit operator AChar(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return '\x0000';

        if (value.Length > 1)
            throw new InvalidCastException("String contains more than 1 character.");

        return value[0];
    }

    public static explicit operator AChar(long value)
    {
        if(value < 0 || value > 0xFF)
            throw new InvalidCastException("Char code is out of ASCII range.");

        return (AChar)Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { (byte)value });
    }

    public static implicit operator AChar(byte value) => (AChar)(long)value;
    public static explicit operator AChar(int value) => (AChar)(long)value;

    public static implicit operator char(AChar aChar) => aChar.Value;
    public static implicit operator string(AChar aChar) => aChar.Value.ToString();

    public static bool operator==(AChar left, AChar right) =>
        left.Value == right.Value;

    public static bool operator!=(AChar left, AChar right) =>
        left.Value != right.Value;

    public static bool operator >(AChar left, AChar right) =>
        left.Value > right.Value;

    public static bool operator >=(AChar left, AChar right) =>
        left.Value >= right.Value;

    public static bool operator <(AChar left, AChar right) =>
        left.Value < right.Value;

    public static bool operator <=(AChar left, AChar right) =>
        left.Value <= right.Value;

    public override string ToString() => this;

    public override int GetHashCode() =>    
        Value.GetHashCode();

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is AChar && ((AChar)obj).Value == Value;

    char Value { get; set; }
}
```

Convert you character code to AChar first, it is compatible with `char` and `string` of C#.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are pretty complete. There is also this C# trick that you can use to get it in the mood for characters:

```
string mystring = "" + (char)7;
```

This works in general for more types that are not directly assignable to a string. It may prove less ugly to you and lets you do more concatenation on the same line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It did not make sense that a char, which is actually the building block of string could not be concatenated. I can see that you cannot make a string equal to a char and that requires a cast, but concatenation however works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is weird that it does not have a conversion operator. Stupid really. In other news, you can similarly get C# in the mood for doing proper int division a similar way: (0.0 + 5) / 2 will correctly give you 2.5 instead of the retarded 2 that C# made up which is not even Math if you tried 5 / 2 = 2 according to the Math wizards at MS.

Comment: Each question stands on its own. Do not link to another question that has nothing to do with this one. This is not a begging site, you are messing up the search mechanisms.